# Updating a mySQL table data using a trigger, with different delimiters, in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, batch-file, sql-update, delimiter

I'm trying to run a batch update on my mySQL tables, from a **csv** file which gets updated every 24 hours. How would I go about updating the entire table from the csv, but ignoring duplicate values that haven't changed over the last 24 hours? So if a customer's number changed that would get updated, but thier name would be ignored and stay the same if it hadn't been altered.

The tables I'm using are **InnoDB**

Probably won't make a difference but my batch script is written in **php**.

Thanks!

LazyTotoro.

**UPDATE:**

Here's my code so far, I'm getting an error due to the delimiters ';'. You can't seem to change these in PHP. Does anyone know a work around?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_customertemp` AFTER INSERT ON customertemp
        FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                IF (NEW.customerRank != (SELECT customerRank FROM customer WHERE customer.id = NEW.id)) THEN
                    SET NEW.customerRank = customer.customerRank
                END IF;

                IF (NEW.customerCode != (SELECT customerCode FROM customer WHERE customer.id = NEW.id)) THEN
                    SET NEW.customerCode = customer.customerCode
                END IF;

                IF (NEW.customerName != (SELECT customerName FROM customer WHERE customer.id = NEW.id)) THEN
                    SET NEW.customerName = customer.customerName
                END IF;

                IF (NEW.customerEmail != (SELECT customerEmail FROM customer WHERE customer.id = NEW.id)) THEN
                    SET NEW.customerEmail = customer.customerEmail
                END IF;

                IF (NEW.customerAddress != (SELECT customerAddress FROM customer WHERE customer.id = NEW.id)) THEN
                    SET NEW.customerAddress = customer.customerAddress
                END IF;

                IF (NEW.customerAdded != (SELECT customerAdded FROM customer WHERE customer.id = NEW.id)) THEN
                    SET NEW.customerAdded = customer.customerAdded
                END IF;
            END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temporary table (ex: yourtable_tmp) in which you can import your csv data and create a trigger AFTER INSERT to make the updates on your conditions and then TRUNCATE temporary table.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response! I'm currently already making temporary tables, the issue i'm facing is how I would actually write the trigger, is there any chance you could shed some more light on how  the syntax works, the documentation is rather confusing. Thanks!

Comment: here is an example of trigger
<pre>
    DELIMITER $$
    USE `db_name`$$
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insert_data`$$
    CREATE
    TRIGGER `insert_data` AFTER INSERT ON table_1
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_2 (col_1, col_2) VALUES ('val_1','val_2');
    END;
    $$
    DELIMITER ;</pre>

Comment: I've updated my question with my code. I'm getting an error when trying to run this in my PHP script. It's down to the delimiters, which I can't chance in PHP. Do you know a work around? Thanks.

Comment: Add `DELIMITER $$` at the start and `$$ DELIMITER ;` at the and and run all in phpmyadmin